# Wrangling shifted DataFrame with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

In the following pandas DataFrame, The first two columns (`Remessas_A` and `Remessas_A_1d`) were given and I had to find the third (`previsao`) following the pattern described below. Notice that I'm not counting the column `DataEntrega` as the first, which is a datetime index.

```
DataEntrega,Remessas_A,Remessas_A_1d,previsao
2020-07-25,696.0,,
2020-07-26,0.0,,
2020-07-27,518.0,,
2020-07-28,629.0,,
2020-07-29,699.0,,
2020-07-30,660.0,,
2020-07-31,712.0,,
2020-08-01,2.0,-672.348684948797,23.651315051203028
2020-08-02,0.0,-504.2138715410994,-504.2138715410994
2020-08-03,4.0,-91.10009092298037,426.89990907701963
2020-08-04,327.0,194.46620611760167,823.4662061176017
2020-08-05,442.0,220.65451760630847,919.6545176063084
2020-08-06,474.0,-886.140302693952,-226.14030269395198
2020-08-07,506.0,-61.28132269808316,650.7186773019168
2020-08-08,11.0,207.12286256242962,230.77417761363265
2020-08-09,2.0,109.36137834671834,-394.85249319438105
2020-08-10,388.0,146.2428764085755,573.1427854855951
2020-08-11,523.0,-193.02046115081606,630.4457449667857
2020-08-12,509.0,-358.59415822684485,561.0603593794635
2020-08-13,624.0,966.9258406162757,740.7855379223237
2020-08-14,560.0,175.8273195122506,826.5459968141674
2020-08-15,70.0,19.337299248463978,250.11147686209662
2020-08-16,3.0,83.09413535361391,-311.75835784076713
2020-08-17,401.0,-84.67345026550751,488.4693352200876
2020-08-18,526.0,158.53310638454195,788.9788513513276
2020-08-19,580.0,285.99137337700336,847.0517327564669
2020-08-20,624.0,-480.93226226400344,259.85327565832023
2020-08-21,603.0,-194.68412031046182,631.8618765037056
2020-08-22,45.0,-39.23172496101115,210.87975190108546
2020-08-23,2.0,-115.26376570266325,-427.0221235434304
2020-08-24,463.0,10.04635376084557,498.5156889809332
2020-08-25,496.0,-32.44638720124206,756.5324641500856
2020-08-26,600.0,-198.6715680014182,648.3801647550487
2020-08-27,663.0,210.40991269713578,470.263188355456
2020-08-28,628.0,40.32391720053602,672.1857937042416
2020-08-29,380.0,-2.4418918145294626,208.437860086556
2020-08-30,0.0,152.66166068424076,-274.3604628591896
2020-08-31,407.0,18.499558564880928,517.0152475458141
```

The first 7 values of `Remessas_A_1d` and `previsao` are nulls, and will be kept nulls.

In order to obtain the first 7 non nulls values of `previsao`, from `2020-08-01` to `2020-08-07`, I've made a shift of the `Remessas_A` 7 days ahead and I've added the rows of the shifted `Remessas_A` and the original `Remessas_A_1d`:

```
#res is the name of the dataframe
res['previsao'].loc['2020-08-01':'2020-08-07'] = res['Remessas_A'].shift(7).loc['2020-08-01':'2020-08-07'].add(res['Remessas_A_1d'].loc['2020-08-01':'2020-08-07'])
```

To find the next 7 values of `previsao`, from `2020-08-08` to `2020-08-14`, now I shifted the `previsao` column 7 days ahead and I've added the rows of the shifted `previsao` and the original `previsao`:

```
res['previsao'].loc['2020-08-08':'2020-08-14'] = res['previsao'].shift(7).loc['2020-08-08':'2020-08-14'].add(res['Remessas_A_1d'].loc['2020-08-08':'2020-08-14'])
```

To find the next values of `previsao`, I repeated the last step, moving 7 days ahead each time:

```
res['previsao'].loc['2020-08-15':'2020-08-21'] = res['previsao'].shift(7).loc['2020-08-15':'2020-08-21'].add(res['Remessas_A_1d'].loc['2020-08-15':'2020-08-21'])
res['previsao'].loc['2020-08-22':'2020-08-28'] = res['previsao'].shift(7).loc['2020-08-22':'2020-08-28'].add(res['Remessas_A_1d'].loc['2020-08-22':'2020-08-28'])
res['previsao'].loc['2020-08-29':'2020-08-31'] = res['previsao'].shift(7).loc['2020-08-29':'2020-08-31'].add(res['Remessas_A_1d'].loc['2020-08-29':'2020-08-31'])
#the last line only spaned 3 days because I reached the end of my dataframe
```

Instead of doing that by hand, how can I create a function that would take `periods=7`, `Remessas_A` and `Remessas_A_1d` as input and would give `previsao` as the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most elegant code, but this should do the trick:

```
df["previsao"][df.index <= pd.to_datetime("2020-08-07")] = df["Remessas_A"].shift(7) + df["Remessas_A_1d"]

for d in pd.date_range("2020-08-08", "2020-08-31"):
    df.loc[d, "previsao"] = df.loc[d - pd.Timedelta("7d"), "previsao"] + df.loc[d, "Remessas_A_1d"]
```

Edit: I've assumed you have `DataEntrega` as an index and datetime object. Can post the rest of the code if you need.